# SQL query search

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

Hi

I'm trying to learn SQL queries, but I would like some help. I'm trying to find a query where for example I can search for rows of data from a database time e.g. search for where the values equal Z370, 0631 and 048X.

What would be the query you would use to filter out this information?

Comment: What columns need to equal Z370, 0631, 048x? Or is it any of them?

Comment: What have you tried? Based on the above, can you provide what you want your sql query to return?

Comment: let's say the database contains 1000 rows of data, and I'm looking specifically to search for Z370, 0631 and 048X throughout the database. What would be the query you would use? Let's assume that Z0631 can be in test1 or test2 (sorry for the image displaying two test1's)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to search multiple columns, then you need to use 'OR' clauses and check for the values in each column separately.  The 'IN' keyword lets you check a value against a supplied list:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   tablename 
WHERE  test1 IN ( 'Z370', 'O631', 'O48X' ) 
       OR test2 IN ( 'Z370', 'O631', 'O48X' )
```

NB: The real name of your table should replace tablename (without quotes).

Comment: nono, I'm looking for Z370 and 0631 and 048X in the same row. How can i search for this?

Answer (score 1):

Use this tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_syntax.asp to learn syntax for sql queries.

Basic syntax is this:

```
SELECT columns FROM table WHERE column = 'value'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you first need to define unique names for your columns. You can't have test1 3 times.
Also,each row should (must) have primary key for any of your rows to make sense.

But the command for getting something from a DB would be

```
SELECT [names of columns] FROM [name of table] WHERE [column name]=value
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a series of steps that will enable the behavior that you seek.
It will describe how to do the following:

1: build a procedure that splits delineated values and returns a table with each value.

2: Build a procedure that checks if a row is qualified to be returned in your query.

-2.1: Place user values into a temp table using step 1.

-2.2: Place row values into a temp table using step 1.

-2.3: Count the number of rows in 2.2 where 2.1 contains a row value from 2.2.

-2.4: If 2.3 = number of values in 2.1 then return true.

3: Select values from your table where Step2 = true.

Here is a procedure to split strings

```
CREATE function [dbo].[f_split]
(
@param nvarchar(max), 
@delimiter char(1)
)
returns @t table (val nvarchar(max), seq int)
as
begin
set @param += @delimiter
;with a as
(
select cast(1 as bigint) f, charindex(@delimiter, @param) t, 1 seq
union all
select t + 1, charindex(@delimiter, @param, t + 1), seq + 1
from a
where charindex(@delimiter, @param, t + 1) > 0
)
insert @t
select substring(@param, f, t - f), seq from a
option (maxrecursion 0)
return
end
```

Here id a function that returns false if a given row has less than 100% matches
Keep in mind that this is not optimized and is formatted to clearly demonstrate a concept.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Row_MeetsCriteria_FullText]
(
    @RowID Int,
    @Criteria Nvarchar(Max)
)
RETURNS Bit
AS
BEGIN
Declare @Result as Bit = 1
Declare @IntResult as int = 0
Declare @test1ColumnValue Nvarchar(4) = (Select Test1 from TestdataTable where TESTID = @RowID)
Declare @test2ColumnValue Nvarchar(4) = (Select Test2 from TestdataTable where TESTID = @RowID)
Declare @test3ColumnValue Nvarchar(4) = (Select Test3 from TestdataTable where TESTID = @RowID)
Declare @result1ColumnValue Nvarchar(4) = (Select Result1 from TestdataTable where TESTID = @RowID)
Declare @result2ColumnValue Nvarchar(4) = (Select Result2 from TestdataTable where TESTID = @RowID)
Declare @result3ColumnValue Nvarchar(4) = (Select Result3 from TestdataTable where TESTID = @RowID)
    if @Result = 1 --Continue checking
    Begin
        If LEN(@Criteria) > 0
        begin
            Declare @allStrings Nvarchar(Max)
            set @allStrings = (@test1ColumnValue + N' ' + @test2ColumnValue + N' ' +@test3ColumnValue  + N' ' +@result1ColumnValue  + N' ' +@result2ColumnValue + N' ' +@result3ColumnValue)
            declare @CriteriaTable Table (Criteria Nvarchar(MAX),seq int)
            insert into @CriteriaTable Select * from dbo.f_split(@Criteria,' ')
             declare @Matches int = (select Count(Criteria) from @CriteriaTable     Where @allStrings Like(Criteria))
             Declare @NumberOfCriteria int = (select COUNT(Criteria) from @CriteriaTable)
             Set @IntResult = ((100 / @NumberOfCriteria) * @Matches)
            if @IntResult < 100
            begin
            Set @Result = 0
            end
        end
    end
RETURN @result
END
```

Now just query your table against the function
Client enteres this value "1z27 2345 tthy you8"

your procedure

select * from testdata where dbo.rowmeetscriteria(RowID, "1z27 2345 tthy you8")

To make this optimized, do things like avoiding double query by passing the row values directly into the procedure.